# How can I get the number of differences between two types of array without casting

Tags: arrays, casting, comparison

I have two types of arrays with the same length:

```
array1: [2,1,2,3,1]
array2: ["2","2","2","2","1"]
```

I want to compare them and get the number of differences without casting. For example, for the arrays above, I'm expecting to get the output: 2

Comment: Does array 2 absolutely have to be strings?

Comment: If the second array are just integer as string could simply `parseInt()` the value before checking if it is inside the first array.

Comment: Question like this should show what you tried and also include what the expected results are

Comment: There is no such thing as "array type". Each item of an array can be whatever value, even if the type is different than other items.

Comment: I made the question more clear this time :)

Comment: That is not a proper description of criteria and expected results. Please use proper sentences and put a bit of effort into question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function return the number of elements that different between arrays.

```
  function compareArrays(x,y){
       var diff = 0;
       x.forEach((elem,index)=>{
             if(y[index]!=elem){
                 diff++;
             }
      });
      return diff;
   }
```

I use == in  y[index]==elem thus 1=='1' is true.

Comment: Thanks Alon, it's working! can yo explain what x.forEach((elem,index) means?

Comment: forEach executes a provided function once per array element.
in this case it run function that check if the element in y[index]==elem  while elem is the element x[index].

Comment: Ok, got it. thanks Alon.

Answer (score 1):

use triple equal to compare element without automatic type coercion

```
function compareArrays(a1, a2){
    var diff = 0;
    a1.forEach(function(v,i) {  
        if(v !== a2[i]){
            diff++;
        }
    });
    return diff;
}



var array1 = [2,1,2,3,1];
var array2 =  ["2","2","2","2","1"]

compareArrays(array1, array2); //return 5
```

Comment: I don't want to return true/false, but how many differences exists

Comment: @A.Man that's what you get for being vague in your question

Comment: You are right. I edited the question

Comment: You didn't mention about array length. I assume you want to compare arrays of same length.

Comment: correct. it will always be the same length

Comment: @A.Man I've updated the solution. check if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried the code. it's not returning the expected result

Comment: @A.Man sorry that was my fault. it should work now.

Comment: not going to work without coercing numbers or using `!=` instead of `!==`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a for loop that converts the strings in array2 to integers and store them in array3. Then easily compare array3 with array1. Or just do the comparison inside of the for loop - no need to create a third array.

Answer (score 0):

A well known trick in JavaScript for comparing arrays of integers or of strings of integers (like your example)

```
var ll=["12","45","78"];
var l=[12,45,78];

document.write(l.join(',')==ll.join(','));
```